# Multiple SessionFactory/TransactionManager : no session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having two databases running in parallel.

I created two configs with different GenericDAOs/SessionFactories for each one, however the second SessionFactory to be instantiated have issues. When I try to **getCurrentSession()** I get this error : **org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread**.

**Config1.xml** :

```
<bean id="mainDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/main" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="mainSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.avocat.domain.entities.main.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mainTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mainSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="mainTransactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

**Config2.xml** :

```
<bean id="fakeDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fake" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="fakeSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="fakeDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.avocat.domain.entities.intra.Bla</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fakeTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="fakeDataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="fakeSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="fakeTransactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

**MainGenericDAO** :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mainSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory mainSessionFactory;

protected Session currentSession()
{
    return mainSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

**FakeGenericDAO** :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fakeSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory fakeSessionFactory;

protected Session currentSession()
{
    return fakeSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Config1 is declared before Config2. 
Also, queries using MainGenericDAO/MainSessionFactory are OK.
But **currentSession()** from FakeGenericDAO returns the error.

Comment: Did you use the @Transactional annotation?

Comment: Yes, I did. Should I specify something after @Transactional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the transaction is not created on your second `DAO` for the `FakeSessionFactory`. You must use `@Transactional("fakeTransactionManager")` on the `FakeGenericDAO`.